# What's the difference between 'juste', 'seul' and 'seulement'?

Tags: anglais, adverbes

I'm a beginner and I want to translate the phrase 'my family is only my mother and I', but I'm having trouble choosing the correct adverb. 'Juste' seems to have more meanings and I haven't encountered it in similar phrases as much. Whereas, I'm not sure if 'seul' would be correct because it also means 'alone'. 'Seulement' seems like the best option to me, but I would like to know what the difference between these three words is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need an adverb for this sentence, which rules out 'seul'.

I personally would understand 'Ma famille est composée juste de ma mère et de moi' perfectly but I think 'Ma famille est composée seulement de ma mère et de moi' works better here, since 'juste' conveys the idea of precision whereas 'seulement' insists on the idea of small quantity.